# GoogleMock - Returning a value based on mocked function variables

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I'm trying to mock a function that accepts a struct and returns another one. Something like

```
struct InParams {
  int important_value;
  int other_value;
}

struct OutParams {
  int same_important_value;
  int idk_something;
}

virtual OutParams MyClass::TransformParams(const InParams& params){
...
}
```

When making a mocking function I want the OutParam struct to be dependant of InParam. So I made a mocking class and function

```
class MockMyClass : public MyClass {
public:
  MOCK_METHOD(OutParams, TransformParams,
              (const InParams& params), (const, override));
};

OutParams FakeOutParams(const InParams& in_parm){
  return {in_parm.important_value, 1};
}
```

And in expectant call I try to use it like this

```
auto fake_wrapper = new MockMyClass();
EXPECT_CALL(*fake_wrapper, TransformParams(_))
      .WillRepeatedly(
          WithArg<0>(Return(FakeOutParams)));
```

Which fails to compile. I also tried using SaveArgPointee but since InParams wasnt a pointer it also wasn't enough

What can I do to fix my issue?

Comment: `.WillRepeatedly(Invoke(FakeOutParams));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `Return` it takes the object of returned type as argument, by copy. If you want to be more generic, and alter your return value with respect to some logic, use a gmock action. E.g. `Invoke` will be fine here:

```
EXPECT_CALL(*fake_wrapper, TransformParams(_))
      .WillRepeatedly(Invoke([](const InParams& params) { return FakeOutParams(params); })));
```

or directly move logic to lambda:

```
EXPECT_CALL(*fake_wrapper, TransformParams(_))
      .WillRepeatedly(Invoke([](const InParams& params) {
      return OutParams{ params.important_value, 1 };
})));
```